# How can I move files with Google Drive API v3 (perl)

Tags: perl, google-drive-api, mojolicious

I'm trying to move a file that I uploaded separately to Google Drive from one folder to another.

When I do:

```
my $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' . $id;

my $tx  = $ua->patch(
    $url,
    json => {
        addParents    => '0ByFk4UawESNUcEhWdjBWTVRXZ1E',
    }
);
```

The name of the file is changed, but the parent folder (which is the root folder for my Google Drive) is still the same.

I am doing something wrong for sure, but what?

My client is a [`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent) object, but it doesn't seem to matter much. Everything else works OK.

I am aware of similar questions for other languages such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903908/moving-files-with-google-drive-api-v3) but they don't seem to translate well for me.

Comment: Re "*I am aware of similar questions for other languages but they don't seem to translate well for me.*", It might for us. Please provide!

Comment: Please set up a public file structure that we can use to test. It's very possible that `0ACFk4UawESNUUk9PVA` and `0ByFk4UawESNUcEhWdjBWTVRXZ1E` are simply wrong. And please use something like [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) to manipulate URLs. Concatenating strings isn't safe.

Comment: *"The name of the file is changed, but the parent folder (which is the root folder for my Google Drive) is still the same"* This troubles me. Are you expecting to rename your root folder? Please describe precisely what that `patch` call is supposed to do, including what both of those IDs mean. And add links to the Google documentation that you think supports what you have written.

Comment: @borodin - I edited to eliminate the file renaming part, I hope the snippet is clearer now. The documentation is at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update. The  id `0ByFk4UawESNUcEhWdjBWTVRXZ1E` is verified, it comes from the same API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addParents` and `removeParents` must be added as parameters, not in the JSON payload.

This works:

```
my $url = Mojo::URL->new('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileID');

$url->query({ addParents    => 'parentIdToBeAdded',
              removeParents => 'parentIdToBeRemoved' });

my $tx = $ua->patch($url, json => { modifiedTime  => '2017-06-04T10:00:00-02:00' });
```

Some other - as in the request above - are added in the JSON body.

Basically anything that in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update) is under 'Required query parameters' and 'Optional query parameters' goes in as query, 'Optional Properties' go in the JSON request body.