# Request had insufficient authentication scopes with google drive

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

So I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903908/moving-files-with-google-drive-api-v3) for trying out file transferring from folder to folder using Google Drive API. Then I hit a snag:

> Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

It seems that the scopes I defined were not the right ones: /drive.appdata & /drive.file. I wanted to try the /drive one, but that needs verification.
Is there a way to bypass verification so I can test moving files without needing my app to be verified? Or is there another way to move files around in Google Drive without resorting to having your app verified? The account I am using for testing is disposable anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

*Note: this message has nothing to do with application verification.*

This message means that the authentication credentials for the user you have logged in to do not contain the permissions that you need to do what it is you are trying to do.

Determine which method you are trying to call that is resulting in this message check the documentation to ensure that you are requesting the correct scopes.  Then reauthenticate the user.  You need to see a new consent screen popping up.

[file.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) for example requiters the following permissions.

[image]

Remember if you changed your code you need to force the user to reauthencate or your just running with the old scopes.

Comment: I see. So I should just add these in the OAuth consent screen. I don't need to have it verified? I just need it defined in the scope? I'll test it out.

Comment: Yes you should just add one of those scopes to your application.   Your app will need to be verified before you go to production but its unrelated to the error message you are getting.

Comment: Oh yeah! It worked! Ahahahaha!
Edit: Thank you very much.